# Log both error status code and error status message with Spring Webflux Webclient

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

*What I would like to achieve:*

Send http requests with a body MyPojo to an external API and return the original MyPojo.
But when there is an error (external API not returning 200) log the error code and the error message body (without throwing anything!) and still return the original MyPojo.

*What did I try:*

```
    public Flux<MyPojo> question (Flux<MyPojo> myPojoFlux) {
        return myPojoFlux.flatMap(myPojo -> webClient.post().bodyValue(myPojo).exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> logStatusCodeAndErrorBodyWhenNotStatusOk(clientResponse, myPojo)));
    }

    private Mono<MyPojo> logStatusCodeAndErrorBodyWhenNotStatusOk(final ClientResponse clientResponse, final MyPojomyPojo) {
        if (200 != clientResponse.statusCode().value()) {
            //Not able to get the error message body :'(
            LOGGER.warn("The third party API responded status code {} with error message body {} for this request payload {}", clientResponse.statusCode().value(), myPojo, null);
            //Note: I do not want to throw any exception here
        }
//return the original payload mypojo object
        return Mono.just(myPojo);
    }
```

I also tried onError, onStatus, no luck

*Question :*

With this construct, I am able to get the status code, but not the error message body, while returning a strange Mono with Mono.just(myPojo);

How to log both the status code and the error message body without (throwing anything) and being able to return the original request payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```java
public Flux<MyPojo> question(Flux<MyPojo> myPojoFlux) {
    return myPojoFlux.flatMap(myPojo -> webClient.post()
        .bodyValue(myPojo)
        .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
            if (clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                return clientResponse
                    .releaseBody() // be a good citizen and consume the body
                    .thenReturn(myPojo);
            } else {
                return clientResponse
                    .bodyToMono(String.class) // consume the body to construct response
                    .doOnNext(response -> LOG.warn("Error {} occurred. HTTP status code was {}", response, clientResponse.statusCode()))
                    .thenReturn(myPojo);
            }
        })
    );
}
```